# List structure with R

Tags: r, list

I have a list with this structure:

```
> str(move.spl)

List of 21
 $ 1001269:'data.frame':    931 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ from: Factor w/ 58 levels "Aalborg Portland",..: 12 11 52 51 44 44 20 51 47 48 ...
  ..$ to  : Factor w/ 58 levels "Aalborg Portland",..: 11 52 51 44 44 20 51 47 48 43 ...
 $ 1001570:'data.frame':    931 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ from: Factor w/ 58 levels "Aalborg Portland",..: 12 11 52 51 44 44 20 51 47 48 ...
  ..$ to  : Factor w/ 58 levels "Aalborg Portland",..: 11 52 51 44 44 20 51 47 48 43 ...
```

I would like to get it as a table, so I used `moves <- do.call(rbind, move.spl)`. But this does not work for large files (RAM issues).

I am trying to understand the structure of the list. It seems that there are different data.frame in it. How can I remove these levels with the 7 digits (1001269 here in the example) and just to keep the rest?

Comment: Can you try `library(data.table); moves1 <- rbindlist(move.spl)` on a fresh session

Comment: It works very well on a sample but not on my full dataset... I still have RAM issues, and I already have 48 GB of RAM... Thank you anyway. I think I will work on division of the data and merge the tables later on...

Comment: Then, you may need to use a machine with more RAM

Comment: Well, 48 GB is already quite big... I think I can re-think my work flow for this issue...

Comment: Or perhaps use the RevoScaleR

Comment: Yes, I will have to dig to this new world... thank you anyway!

Comment: Currently, I am doing a comparison on SAS dataset reading with RevoScaleR vs. other packages in R.  The RevoScaleR is very fast in importing

Comment: or the new `spark` package

Comment: Is this just a sample? Because 21*931 rows isn't big at all.

Comment: @HongOoi, it is just a sample yes. The real data is 296438 * 9 columns.

Comment: Even 300000 rows isn't that big nowadays.

Comment: I know... I have also tried an other function (`moves <- do.call(rbind, move.spl`) but the computer is still crashing...

Comment: Sorry. The actual list is quite big, 70 GB. The 296438 * 9 columns is the input table. I will work with divisions...